# How to dynamically add items in ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am facing a problem when I add data in `ListView`. The problem is that `ListView` add data first time correctly but the second-time data is added it replaces the previous row with new data. Here is my list view XAML and XAMl.cs

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="invoiceLV" Height="207" Margin="154,88,-752,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="914">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductCode}" Width="150" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductName }" Width="150 " />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Units" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Unit}" Width="150"  />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Unit Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UnitPrice}" Width="120"  />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Size(gm)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}" Width="120"  />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" GST %" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GST}" Width="100"  />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" Width="120"  />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

public partial class Invoice : UserControl
{
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inv.calculation();
        invoiceLV.Items.Add(inv);
    }
}
```

And Binding class is:

```
class Invoice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string productcode;
    string productname;
    double unitprice;
    int size;
    double gst;
    double price;
    string code;
    string name;
    int unit;

    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            if (price != value)
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }
    }

    public double GST
    {
        get { return gst; }
        set
        {
            if (gst != value)
            {
                gst = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GST");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Size
    {
        get { return size; }
        set
        {
            if (size != value)
            {
                size = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Size");
            }
        }
    }

    public double UnitPrice
    {
        get { return unitprice; }
        set
        {
            if (unitprice != value)
            {
                unitprice = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UnitPrice");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return productname; }
        set
        {
            if (productname != value)
            {
                productname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ProductCode
    {
        get { return productcode; }
        set
        {
            if (productcode != value)
            {
                productcode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProductCode");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Code
    {
        get { return code; }
        set
        {
            if (code != value)
            {
                code = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Code");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set
        {
            if (unit!= value)
            {
                unit= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Unit");
            }
        }
    }

    public void calculation()
    {
        Bussiness.Invoice i = new Bussiness.Invoice();
        ProductName = i.Name(this);
        ProductCode = code;
        Unit = Unit;
        UnitPrice = i.Unit(this);
        GST = 18;
        Size = i.Size(this);
        Price =unit* (UnitPrice + (UnitPrice * (GST / 100)));

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

}

And the screenshots are given below.

**Image after one record**

[image: Image after one record]

**Image after two records**

[[image: image after two records][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzoPG.png)

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you should learn MVVM and bind your collection to your listview. But to solve this problem, you are using the same instance of `Invoice` to be added again and again. Create new instance and then add.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var inv = new Invoice();
    inv.calculation();
    invoiceLV.Items.Add(inv);


}
```

Comment: hey #Nitin thanx for help. but I am still facing same problem :(

Comment: okay finally I solved it. I have to bind data again after new instance created. like in above code at the end this line must be added. DataContext=inv;

Answer (score 2):

It is because everytime you hit the button you are replacing the same instance of `inv` with different value. The MVVM way to do it is by setting it's itemsource and binding it to a collection.

```
 ObservableCollection<Invoice> _yourItemSource= new ObservableCollection<Invoice>(); 
 invoiceLV.ItemsSource = _yourItemSource;


  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

         var inv = new Invoice();
         inv.calculation();
         _yourItemSource.Add(inv);

  }
```

Comment: heyy Kayle.. should I make "_yourItemSource" in constructor or behind button?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      var invoice = new Invoice();
      invoice.calculation();
      invoiceLV.Items.Add(invoice);
  //Add items to your listview by above code!
}
```

You can also bind the data into same way!